# Allow Content Author to Publish, But Not Edit or Delete

Tags: author, user-roles

I am hiring a content writer for my WordPress blog. I will be the sole blog admin. I need to define a role for this writer.

I was wondering if there was a WordPress user role that will allow him to publish posts and pages (even without admin approval), but not be able to Edit or Delete them once published (or only do this after admin approval). I need this in case he has a change of heart and decides to ruin the site by removing all posts he created or replacing them with rubbish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new user role, and then assign that role to the user when you create their account. In your `functions.php`:

```
add_role('content_writer', 'Content Writer', array(
    'read' => true,
    'publish_posts' => true,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'delete_posts' => false,
));
```

You can see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for an additional listing of available roles and capabilities.