# Allow user to Publish, but not Edit or Delete

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I saw post [Allow Content Author to Publish, But Not Edit or Delete](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88553/allow-content-author-to-publish-but-not-edit-or-delete) but is not the same I need and I cannot ask there because of reputation ¬¬

I need an user that can publish any user's post but can't edit or delete any post, not only their.

I tried with capabilites **Read|Publish Post** but can't see the Posts. With **Read|Edit Posts|Publish Post** can see the Posts but only publish own Posts.

Is there a way of doing what I need ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're trying to do by not allowing Edit. Its only a job of Publishing the post it seems. (or maybe add some Meta description etc)

But, if you're looking at creating a Moderator, you need to create additional user group & assign permissions.

You can try http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/ or similar plugins to modify granular permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finishing up a project where we used [Theme Hybrid's Members Plugin](http://themehybrid.com/plugins/members).  It gives you granular control over what each role can do (you can also easily create custom roles), and this plugin would allow you to permit a user to post, but not edit or delete a post.

There are more "advanced" ways of doing this, but I say, "pick you battles" and make use of a great free plugin as long as it doesn't create other problems for you.