# Admin menu disable new/delete page

Tags: customization, pages, admin

So I've been tinkering with the admin roles and I can't seem to be able to revoke create page rights for the admin. I can only find 'Edit page'.

If I remove Edit page, the entire pages tab goes away(probably because of not enough rights)..

Is there a way to disable creating/deleting pages and keep the pages tab?

I have this so far.

```
$role = get_role('administrator');
$role->remove_cap('delete_pages');
$role->remove_cap('delete_others_pages');
$role->remove_cap('delete_published_pages');
$role->remove_cap('publish_pages');
```

Comment: what is your code and what you need to achieve by keep the pages tab if it is not used?

Comment: The admin can edit that page if needed. But I don't want him to create/delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the capability of deleting published pages and publishing pages, I have effectively stopped the admin from creating or deleting anything that is on the website.

```
$role = get_role('administrator');  
$role->remove_cap('delete_published_pages');  
$role->remove_cap('publish_pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

If achieving this with a plugin is acceptable to you, an [answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/135033/7313) recommended the [Advanced Access Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/).

Comment: I would rather do it myself unless there is no other option. But thank you for the plugin, if I can't find out how to do it i'll just use it!